# Will a print out from TurboTax satisfy the I-864 (or I-864ez)?

Tags: immigration, taxes, uscis

The I-864ez says,

> Item Numbers 5.a. - 6.c. Federal Income Tax Information. You must provide either an IRS transcript or a photocopy
> from your own records of your Federal individual income tax return for the most recent tax year. If you believe additional
> returns may help you to establish your ability to maintain sufficient income, you may submit transcripts or photocopies of
> your Federal individual income tax returns for the three most recent years.

> **You are not required to have the IRS certify the transcript or photocopy unless specifically instructed to do so by a
> Government official; a plain transcript or photocopy is acceptable**

Does the print out from a digitally filed TurboTax return qualify as acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your quote:

> or photocopies of your Federal individual income tax returns for the three most recent years

If you filed through turbo tax - then you can print out a "photocopy" of your filed return through the software.

You can download the transcripts directly from the IRS if you want to avoid any doubt, but your own copy of the submitted return (provided you sign it where it needs to be signed) should suffice.

Comment: I have no idea if that's a photocopy. I don't know how e-filing works. But if that's good enough for them, I'm good.